# IE8 on Windows 7 gives user HTTP Error 400 on all ASP.NET websites

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, asp.net

I have a user on an SBS 2003 domain who cannot surf any ASP.NET webpage [asp/aspx] using IE8 on Windows 7.

Notable websites include pretty much all of Microsoft, the domain Intranet and a few other sites that the user uses on a daily basis.  These websites all work correctly in Firefox and Chrome.

There is no problem with DNS, IP address, gateway or any other connectivity settings.  This problem affects *only* this user.  Running IE8 as an Administrator will load ASP.NET websites correctly.  I also tried a few other user accounts on the same machine and they too have no problems.

The only thing the user reports doing at the time was updating Flash.  I have completely removed Flash from the system and this has not made any difference.  I have run scans for malware and nothing showed up.  I have tried running IE8 with no addons at all and even completely removed IE8 from the system and reinstalled it.  Again, no go.

Any help would be appreciated as this has got me stumped!

---

**UPDATE**
I have, thankfully, solved my problem!

It turns out the problem was with the user's User-Agent string.  It was full of gibberish and HTML character codes - `&quot;` for example and long number strings.  I tracked it down to one of the many User-Agent string entries in the machine's registry.  Nuked them, and sure enough, the problem went away!

Comment: wow. kind of scary how that happened.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of an ASP.NET server, you should connect to it and check the logs.

The root cause is probably a local problem, but without seeing the web server interaction, it might be hard to figure out.

Comment: I have checked all the IIS logs I could find on the server and I can't find anything that even relates to that particular laptop, let alone any errors.  Are there any logs outside of the C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles folder I should be looking at? [IIS is not my strong point!].